# create element (commenting box) in *ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

i've built a website i.e. a blog which runs at the moment locally with the full MEAN (MongoDB, Node, Angular and Express) stack. I've already implemented the backend, but have some problems for the frontend. Most of it works. I load the content dynamically i.e. every time the user reached the bottom of the page, i load the next three blog posts. I've also added some voting (up and down). I don't know if i did it right, but it works. I have an array which contains all blog post. Every time the user reached the bottom, i add them via .push to my array. This array is shown via *ngFor, so it contains all current blog post and "future posts". The question arise how i add the voting in an efficient way? I've added an array, every time a user clicks "vote up" i check if the post id is already in that array, if not i add it and increment the vote by one and store the value also in the database by a request. If the user regrets his decision he can anytime press the same button to bring the initial state back, because now the post id is in that array and therefore a click on the same button is not a vote up anymore rather we decrease the vote and remove the post id from the array (and store the new value in the database). The user can now again vote up, because the post id is no more in that array, etc.

Is there any better approach to implement the voting? I think if the user loads 1000 blog articles and votes many articles and afterwards regrets one, then the loading time can eventually very high (finding a value in a big array, etc.).

The point why i've written here is the following. The main problem is that i want to add a commenting box to each blog post. But how do i do that? Should i create each time the browser loads 3 article 3 commenting boxes? "This" is not really a problem, but what happened in the same scenario as already mentioned? What happened if the user reads 20 articles one after the other. Then 20 commenting boxes are created and are binded to some variables, etc. It cant be efficient in that way. I thought i could create one commenting box and every time the user clicks on an anchor tag (named "Reply") the commenting box will be opened. But there exists only one box. It will be shown in the appropriate place. But i don't know how to implement this with angular. :(

I'd appreciate any hint or help. :)

**UPDATE 26.11.2017:** i share some content from my project, so can probably better understand what i mean.

This is my blog.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { CarouselConfig } from 'ngx-bootstrap/carousel';

import { BlogPost } from '../shared/blogPost';
import { BlogPostFactory } from '../shared/blogPost-factory';

import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ca-blog',
  templateUrl: './blog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog.component.css'],
  providers: [{provide: CarouselConfig, useValue: {interval: 1500, noPause: true}}]
})
export class BlogComponent implements OnInit {
  private blogPosts: BlogPost[] = [];
  private heartsUp: string[] = [];
  private likesUp: string[] = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    window.onscroll = () => {
      let windowHeight = "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
      let body = document.body;
      let html = document.documentElement;
      let docHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
      let windowBottom = windowHeight + window.pageYOffset;

      if(windowBottom >= docHeight) {
        let urlSearchParams = { last: this.blogPosts.length };

        this.dataService.getBlogPosts(urlSearchParams).subscribe( result => {
          for(let i=0; i<result.length; i++){
            this.blogPosts.push(BlogPostFactory.fromObject(result[i]));
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getBlogPosts().subscribe( result => {
      for(let i=0; i<result.length; i++){
        this.blogPosts.push(BlogPostFactory.fromObject(result[i]));
      }
    });
  }

  incrementHearts(index) : void {
    let idIndex : number = this.heartsUp.indexOf(this.blogPosts[index].id);

    if(idIndex != -1){
      this.blogPosts[index].hearts--;

      this.heartsUp.splice(idIndex, 1);

    } else {
      this.blogPosts[index].hearts++;

      this.heartsUp.push(this.blogPosts[index].id);
    }

    this.dataService.editBlogPost(this.blogPosts[index].id, { hearts: this.blogPosts[index].hearts }).subscribe().unsubscribe();
  }

  incrementLikes(index) : void {
    let idIndex : number = this.likesUp.indexOf(this.blogPosts[index].id);

    if(idIndex != -1){
      this.blogPosts[index].likes--;

      this.likesUp.splice(idIndex, 1);

    } else {
      this.blogPosts[index].likes++;

      this.likesUp.push(this.blogPosts[index].id);
    }

    this.dataService.editBlogPost(this.blogPosts[index].id, { likes: this.blogPosts[index].likes }).subscribe().unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

and blog.component.html is given by

```
<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let blogPost of blogPosts; let i=index">
    <div *ngIf="i !== 0">
      <hr class="my-5">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <article>
          <section>
            <header style="" class="mb-4">
              <h1 style="display:inline" class="m-0 p-0">{{ blogPost.title }}</h1><small style="opacity:0.5" class="d-block d-sm-inline ml-sm-3">zuletzt bearbeitet am {{ blogPost.lastEdited | date }} von <a href="#" style="color:black"><strong>{{ blogPost.author.username }}</strong></a></small>
              <p class="mt-1 mt-sm-auto"><i class="fa fa-tags mr-2"></i><a *ngFor="let hashtag of blogPost.hashtags" href="#" class="badge badge-secondary mr-2">#{{ hashtag }}</a></p>
            </header>

            <div class="m-0 p-0" [innerHTML]="blogPost.body">
            </div>
            <div>
              <small class="heartUp"><a (click)="incrementHearts(i)" [ngStyle]="{'color':heartsUp.includes(blogPost.id) ? '#E63946' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'}"><i class="fa fa-heart mr-1"></i>{{ blogPost.hearts }}</a></small>
              <small class="likeUp"><a (click)="incrementLikes(i)" [ngStyle]="{'color':likesUp.includes(blogPost.id) ? '#3b5998' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'}"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up mr-1"></i>{{ blogPost.likes }}</a></small>
              <small class="reply"><a><i class="fa fa-mail-reply mr-1"></i>Reply</a></small>
            </div>
          </section>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this visualize my problem better.

Answer (score 0):

for your first question it depends how you think about it, you want to disable the vote up? if yes then you need to treat it on the front end side, if not, you can the user let press the vote up and then in the server check for the user id and send a error message back ("you already voted"), for your second question i don't know very well what you mean with there is just 1 box? you mean you have 1 box component? if that makes you confusion, just think on the component as a class that you can instantiate in objects, same for components you can create a lot of  since very one is a diferent instance.

Comment: i want to handle it on the client side, right. I meant that the blog have several blog posts, let's say for example we have 100 blog posts. When each blog posts have its own comment box then i think it's too slow. Maybe i'm wrong, i don't know. I know to realise this, but i think this is not good programming style. Instead of having 100 comment boxes i could have 1 comment box  that i show only on appropriate places, so whenever a user clicks on a "reply" link, i show him this specific comment box. So not every blog post have it's own local comment box rather i have a "global" comment box.

Comment: I imagine your blog post as a unique component where the only thing that changes is the data inside depending on the id of the blog, you don't load comment boxes, you just load data related to the posts, lets say get the 100 posts data(different date, created by, description) and pass the clicked one to inside the component post

Comment: I've added the whole blog.component.ts and blog.component.html in my starting post, probably you can have a look at it when you have enough time. That would be nice.